# Mismatch error when perform if/else for TIMESTAMP value

Tags: teradata

Hi pls help to correct me for this code :

```
CASE WHEN CAST (Status_Start_TS AS TIMESTAMP) < '2018-07-15  0:0:0'
     THEN '2018-07-15'
     ELSE Status_Start_TS
END AS "Start",
```

I want to compare date and time from col `Status_Start_TS` type TIMESTAMP with '2018-07-15  0:0:0'. I got error messsage "Datatype mismatch.."

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your date/timestamp literals, which, as you have written them currently, are just being interpreted as strings.  Try this version:

```
CASE WHEN Status_Start < DATE '2018-07-15'
     THEN DATE '2018-07-15'
     ELSE Status_Start END AS Start
```

If you want to check if `Status_Start` is earlier than midnight of a date, you should be able to just compare against a date literal for that day.

It isn't entirely clear why you thought to compare `Status_Start` against a timestamp, assuming the former is a date, with no formal time component.  Assuming `Status_Start` actually is a timestamp column, then perhaps the following would make more sense:

```
CASE WHEN Status_Start < TIMESTAMP '2018-07-15 00:00:00'
     THEN DATE '2018-07-15'
     ELSE CAST(Status_Start AS DATE) END AS Start
```